# Creating a v8 object for passing into a function template

Tags: c++, c++17, v8, embedded-v8

I am currently trying to create a function that exposes a type to js. I am doing this by passing the name and a set of member functions and variables (variables have not been implemented yet) into a function which takes them, transforms them and exposes the created class to the global object. However for some reason the actual creation of the object to be passed into the constructor function fails.

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::Object> data = v8::Object::New(isolate); // v8 error here
data->Set(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "name"), v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, name));

v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> constructor = v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate>(isolate, v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, [](const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
  if (!info.IsConstructCall()) 
    info.GetIsolate()->ThrowException(
      v8::String::NewFromUtf8(info.GetIsolate(), ((
          std::string("Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor ") + 
          *(v8::String::Utf8Value(info.GetIsolate(), info.Data()->ToObject(info.GetIsolate())->Get(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(info.GetIsolate(), "name"))->ToString(info.GetIsolate())))) + 
          " cannot be invoked without 'new'").c_str()));
  //...
}, data));
```

Comment: This isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Yep, my bad thanks for the correction

Comment: It would be helpful to have a description of what error you're seeing. Also I suggest you break the code down to into smaller pieces. It looks like you're trying to avoid creating short-lived variables but I think you're missing a lot of error checking that should be going on as a consequence of this. Also this way of laying out your code ends up with function calls are nested about 10 deep, makes the code pretty unreadable for anyone trying to help.